# How to connect to wifi while connected to a device through thunderbolt bridge

Tags: wifi, thunderbolt, internet, ethernet

Macbook --> Thunderbolt Ethernet adapter --> Ethernet Cable --> Device under test with IP address

The device under test is not connected to the internet. While I am testing the device I still need an internet connection, but the non internet device connected with the Thunderbolt Ethernet adapter takes over and I cannot connect to the internet through wifi.

Comment: Maybe I get you wrong, but I am wondering why this should not work? At work I have my MBP connected to the LAN via a Thunderbolt Dock with an ethernet port, though I am able to enable/disable wifi and to use the internet via wifi.

Comment: @northsea Your setup shouldn't work, as far as I know. I've noticed the same thing that macOS prefers the wired connection if it's available. If you're connected to the LAN, you may be getting an internet connection from there.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard Hm... maybe. I will check that on Monday morning.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard No it works. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Network. In the
   list on the left, you see the connections/services.
2. Click the Action pop-up menu at the bottom, then choose Set Service
   Order.

   [image]
3. Drag a service, in your case WiFi, to the top of the list.

   [image]
4. Click OK, then click Apply to make the new settings active.